# Why does it require a reboot after copy/cutting/pasting a file/folder?

Tags: java, android, performance

I am working on a small File manager to get the hang of things on Android and I have cut/copy/paste operation. It seems to work fine, but I run into issues with pasting things. On my app it is displayed fine, but for it to be recognized by other apps, it requires that I reboot the phone. For example, if I cut/paste an image from the download folder to the DCIM folder, the gallery app does not display that image unless I reboot the whole phone. I am using an algorithm that takes data byte by byte. Its extremely inefficient, but I am not totally sure how to implement a faster algorithm.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No actually you wont need to reboot our phone. When you copy an image and paste it to other location your newly copied media file is not added to the `android`'s `ContentResolver`. So you should scan your data using the class [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html)

`Eg:`

When you paste a file you have the file right ?

Modify as your wish, this works fine

```
private void scanImage(File targetLocation) {
    // Scans the media to load images
    String mimetype = Utility.getMimeType(targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
    if(mimetype.contains("image"))
    {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] { targetLocation.getPath() }, new String[] { "image/jpeg" }, this);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Callback should be like

either you can implement `OnScanCompletedListener` in your class and add unimplemented method, So you can pass `this` as callback OR you can use

```
OnScanCompletedListener listener = new OnScanCompletedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        // you will get the callback here

    }
};
```

and pass `listener` as callback

Comment: It says that a callback is required for the MediaScannerConnection.scanFile method

Comment: Sorry i have implemented the method in the class itself , updated the code